# Appcelerator Marketplace can't sign in / download modules

Tags: appcelerator, marketplace

I am logged in to my dashboard with no problems.

Whenever I attempt to download a module or sign into the marketplace itself I get the following error:

That username/password combination is incorrect.

I have logged out and back in.... I have changed my password... I have requested a forgotten password 'reset'.

If I request a password reset while still logged in to my dashboard, all it does is take me to the dashboard proving I'm logged in just fine!

Comment: Are you an indie account user.?

Comment: I tried it now and it is working for me. Can you please check if it is specific to some module or for all. Also when it asks for the credentials, can you re-enter and see if it takes you to the my product page.